# Sending & Receiving SMS via WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, sms

Is there a way to send and receive SMS when a cellular signal is not available, but WiFi is?  I'm often on-site at locations where the building has a strong WiFi (Internet) connection, but a simple cell signal is spotty at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several services exist to send SMS via the Internet. One of the most popular (an possibly most reliable) is [Google Voice](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115116?hl=en).

Answer (score 3):

SMS is tied in with GSM telephony standard, so the answer to your question is No.

But what you can do, is use [Viber](http://www.viber.com), [Whatsapp](http://www.whatsapp.com) to send something similar to SMS (*not the GSM variety!*) to each party *provided* they have the appropriate app installed.

Comment: Isn't there a way to send text messages through an Internet gateway, though?

Comment: That AFAIK requires a specialized SMS-to-Gateway service - for example, this was the first hit on google - http://www.ozekisms.com/ specialized GSM box attached to phone used for mass marketing campaigns over SMS, have not heard of one for personal use though!

Comment: There's actually a huge list of them here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways Not sure how current, but I don't supposed there's a standard or third-party way to route them through one of those?

Comment: You're right, there isn't. Such gateways are expensive to run, so in general they're only open to certain kinds of user (for example, customers of that carrier or online service).

Answer (score 0):

Use smtp to send as email thru sms email gateway. fairly easy to do. Gmail users can send 500 emails per day. 
You can leave the subject blank and send it to the gateway address which is usually something like 15552005555@vtext.com. vtext.com is for text sms only for verizon, also seems to handle many metropcs and walmart numbers. works well for simple text messages. I do it all the time from my email account when i need to text someone and im out of minutes.

refer to the sms gateway list on wikipedia. it really is rediculously simple, the issue is knowing which gateway to which number. typically, users would select their carrier when submitting their number to you say via website. used to see this alot.

the code u need is here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136025/sending-mail-in-android-without-intents-using-smtp